# Input button value is used to append a URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a boilerplate smart way to take the input value, append it to a fixed url like `/search/inputboxvalue` and send the user there. Is there anyway smart robust way to do it? I could use an onlick handler and a form but I wondered if there is a more elegant way to do it, pref just using javascript.

My code:

```
<input name="search" id="search" value="" type="text" width="650px"></input>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = window.location.href + search.value` etc. Of course you'll need some sort of event handler, but you haven't really described how or when this is supposed to happen ?

Comment: Use `getElementById('search').value` to get the value and redirect with `location.href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var my_value = document.getElementById('search').value;
window.location.href = window.location.href + my_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following statment to get value from text box and append to current url.After append it will redirect user to that url.

```
  input_box_value = jQuery('#search').attr('value');
  window.location.href = window.location.href + input_box_value
```

Above 2 statement can be insert on particular event.like click

Answer (score 0):

This is not really correct way to form requests. This symbol "/" should tell us, that we go to subdirectory, or its analog. So, to form this type of url, you will need to use javascript.

But, there is more easy way to create this type of request. Native:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="search">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

This small HTML snippet will allow you to visit an url: `site.com/search?q=inputboxvalue` without any JS. You may even hide submit button and just use Enter to search.